# IAM Policy with `aws:ResourceTag` not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I am trying to create an IAM policy that gives users complete access to dynamodb with the caveat that the tables must have the tag `Stage` with value `Dev` on it. Basically you can create a table but you should add tag `Stage` with value `Dev` on it. You can view/update etc only those tables that have tag as `Stage=Dev`.

AWS documentation mentions a way to do that easily using [Global Context Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html): `aws:ResourceTag`

**But when I use the visual editor I can't find the key in the list of context keys**. If I manually edit the JSON and add the same, I am getting the warning `condition key is not supported`

Here is my policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "OnlyDynamoDBWithTagValueDev",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "dynamodb:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:accountnumber:table/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/Stage": "Dev"
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

What I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are not doing anything wrong. AWS documentation is just incorrect and misleading. `aws:ResourceTag` is not a global condition key as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-resourcetag).

> Global condition keys are condition keys with an aws: prefix. AWS services can provide service-specific keys that include the service prefix. For example, IAM condition keys include the iam: prefix.

According to the documentation, any condition with aws: prefix is a global one. However, if you view conditions for other services, e.g IOT, you will see a service-specific condition with `aws:` prefix, which conflicts with the documentation.

[image: IOT service-level conditions]

Whereas, ECR lists both `ecr:ResourceTag` and `aws:ResourceTag` conditions as service-specific conditions.

[image: ECR service-level conditions]

EC2, on the other hand, only has `ec2:ResourceTag`. RDS has `rds:db-tag`for the same purpose. However, DynamoDb has no service-specific tags for this purpose.

In short, aws:ResourceTag is not a global condition key. Some services create service-specific tags with aws: prefix, even though they are not supposed to do so to align with AWS naming conventions.

I recommend that you create a separate account for development resources.
If you can't do that, you can try changing the logic in your policy as a workaround, e.g. instead of tag conditions, apply naming conventions in your policies, e.g. any table that starts with dev_.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB does not support authorization based on tags so what you are trying to do won't work. see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) for a list of services that do.