# Create AWS Policies-serverless framework

Tags: serverless, aws-access-policy

I am trying to create policies using serverless framework. The idea is to access S3 services, depending on the user's company.

I tried to deploy my `serverless.yaml` with the policy:

```
 - PolicyName: IAM_AWS_S3
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action: '*'
                  Resource: 
                    - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:${AWS::AccountId}-${aws:PrincipalTag/company}'
                    - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:${AWS::AccountId}-${aws:PrincipalTag/company}/*'
```

but I get this error:

> CREATE_FAILED: AuthenticatedRole (AWS::IAM::Role) The policy failed
> legacy parsing (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400;
> Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID:
> da38iiii; Proxy: null)

So, here is my question, is it possible to create a policy before I have a user? can  `PrincipalTag/company` be null?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use PropertyTag for this issue due to I needed to use it in DynamoDB too.
I just create the policies through a Lambda.

Take into account these answers:

- [IAM Policy with `aws:ResourceTag` not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993574/iam-policy-with-awsresourcetag-not-supported)
- [Use tags inside IAM policy resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597355/use-tags-inside-iam-policy-resource)